# Realtime data feed + NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js, serial-port, real-time

would like to have your opinion about my design and technological choices to solve a problem.
I'm getting a continuos data feed (*a speed value V*) from a serial port of a computer connected to a speed sensor through a microcontroller (that sends the value each 30 seconds).

I want to do 2 things :

**- store V and a timestamp to a MongoDB**
**- serve this speed to a webpage and draw a chart.**

Storing V and timestamp is for processing this data and computing few metrics (not in realtime).
I choose Mongo as it's the choice I made for the rest of the app (web app)
(schema less, json, capped collections for my speed logs, realtime things ...)

I'm planning to go with nodejs and a spawn(cat /dev/ttyS0) to get my data feed,
then, I can store it to a local MongoDB and serving it through an http server.

I just found https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport that can be more powerful than my spawn (cat ...)

Would you do the same thing?

And, how would you sync the local MongoDB speed collection with a distant MongoDB database ?

Thanks for your help and ideas !

*PS: I have 3 machines, 3 feeds with 3 different serial ports and 3 node servers / Local MongoDBs...*

Answer (score 1):

Holy Toledo!

It's clear your setup will work. But it's huge overkill just to collect and store maybe 8640 data points over a 24-hour day. Are you sure you want to undertake to install and maintain all of that support software? And then babysit (or train an operator to babysit) that <s>crap?</s> software? And when you move on, well, who's going to inherit your <s>house of cards?</s> system?

I admit I started rasslin' (sp?) serial comm a while ago<sup>1</sup> but I wonder why it's not a 200-line user program, maybe running in the background.<sup>2</sup>

So: How come you need all that stuff?

---

<sup>1</sup> Long before all this *<snicker>* modern froo-fooraw, Sonny *<hack> <hack> <ptui!>* between them twenty-five-mile walks to school through ten feet of bear-infested snow, after we scratched our cuneiform homework on camel-dung tablets by torchlight, dontcha' know. Man, that cave was some humid! In them days, a slice of rancid camel liver was a treat by God and we was damned lucky to get it and a Saturday celebration meant ten minutes alone with the baby raccoon (hey, *watch* them ***teeth***, Sweetheart!) and a quick hit off the peace pipe.

<sup>2</sup> And what's your backup plan when the daily steam outage comes along?

Comment: what the hell are you talking about? is this english?

Comment: This answer made me laugh. I like the humor syntax.